# HTML5 audio for OPUS jumping to end, not transitioning smoothly

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have a server serving OPUS files to a client.

I have an audio element:

```
<audio id="recordingAudioElement" controls autoplay="true" controlsList="nodownload">
  <source src="" type="audio/x-wav">
</audio>
```

In angular 6, I set the set the source of the audio as follows:

```
this.audioElement.src = this.myService.getAudio(id);
```

I have a Java backend method which gets audio from an inputstream and sends it to the client:

```
public HttpServletResponse createServletResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, InputStream inputStream) {

    ServletOutputStream os = null;
    byte[] data;
    try {
        data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);

        response.setContentType("audio/x-wav");
        response.setStatus(200);

        os = response.getOutputStream();
        os.write(data);
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus(500); 
    }
    return response;
}
```

Now, when I set the src of the audio element, the slider remains at the front for long time, does not move, and then it jumps to the end part when last few seconds are left.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding Accept-Ranges:bytes header field in the response.

```
response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media#Handle_HTTP_1.1_byte_range_requests_correctly